# Why I get error message that onVideoSelect is not a function?

Tags: reactjs

I take a tutorial and set a onClick on `<li></li>` , but my log show onVideoSelect is not a function , I can't understand it .

What step I miss it?

```
bundle.js:20945 Uncaught TypeError: onVideoSelect is not a function
```

But I see my onVideoSelect is correct .

developer console show:

onClick is on my `video_list_item.js`

```
bundle.js:20945 Uncaught TypeError: onVideoSelect is not a function
    at onClick (bundle.js:20945)
    at Object.ReactErrorUtils.invokeGuardedCallback (bundle.js:4592)
    at executeDispatch (bundle.js:4392)
    at Object.executeDispatchesInOrder (bundle.js:4415)
    at executeDispatchesAndRelease (bundle.js:3845)
    at executeDispatchesAndReleaseTopLevel (bundle.js:3856)
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at forEachAccumulated (bundle.js:4692)
    at Object.processEventQueue (bundle.js:4061)
    at runEventQueueInBatch (bundle.js:4721)
onClick @ bundle.js:20945
ReactErrorUtils.invokeGuardedCallback @ bundle.js:4592
executeDispatch @ bundle.js:4392
executeDispatchesInOrder @ bundle.js:4415
executeDispatchesAndRelease @ bundle.js:3845
executeDispatchesAndReleaseTopLevel @ bundle.js:3856
forEachAccumulated @ bundle.js:4692
processEventQueue @ bundle.js:4061
runEventQueueInBatch @ bundle.js:4721
handleTopLevel @ bundle.js:4737
handleTopLevelWithoutPath @ bundle.js:14943
handleTopLevelImpl @ bundle.js:14923
perform @ bundle.js:6889
batchedUpdates @ bundle.js:10926
batchedUpdates @ bundle.js:6394
dispatchEvent @ bundle.js:15054
```

Here is my three files about passing `onVideoSelect`

video_list_item.js:

```
const VideoListItem = ({video, onVideoSelect}) => {
  const imageUrl = video.snippet.thumbnails.default.url;
  return (
    <li onClick={() => onVideoSelect(video)} className="list-group-item">
      <div className="video-list media">
        <div className="media-left">
          <img className="media-object" src={imageUrl} />
        </div>
        <div className="media-body">
          <div className="media-heading">{video.snippet.title}</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </li>
  );
};
```

video_list.js:

```
import React from 'react';
import VideoListItem from './video_list_item';
const VideoList = (props) => {
  const videoItems = props.videos.map((video) => {
    return (
      <VideoListItem
        onVideoSelect={props.onVideoSelect}
        key={video.etag} 
        video={video} />
    );
  });
  return (
    <ul className="col-md-4 list-group">
      {videoItems}
    </ul>
  );
};
export default VideoList;
```

index.js:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import YTSearch from 'youtube-api-search';
import SearchBar from './components/search_bar';
import VideoList from './components/video_list';
import VideoDetail from './components/video_detail';
const  API_KEY = 'AIzaSyDUPTN4QS3S356jXT23h72_ftMMxZIo0n4';
class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      videos: [],
      selectedVideo: null
    };
    YTSearch({key: API_KEY, term: 'surfboards'}, (getData) => {
      this.setState({
        videos: getData,
        selectedVideo: getData[0]
      });
    });
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <SearchBar />
        <VideoDetail video={this.state.selectedVideo} />
        <VideoList
          onVideoSelect={selectedVideo => this.setState({selectedVideo}) }
          videos={this.state.videos} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.querySelector('.container'));
```

If I use `<li onClick={console.log(video)} className="list-group-item"></li>`
I can see the value like:
[image]

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, i'm not sure is that what you mean but i have updated my question . Take a look at my question please.

Comment: Can you add a breakpoint and see what the value of onVideoSelect is when you're inside onClick?

Comment: Sorry i'm a new guy with React , i really don't know how to set breakpoint with `Atom` in React.

Comment: I can set <li onClick={console.log(video)} className="list-group-item"></li>

Comment: when does error occur, when page is displayed or when you click on video?

Comment: When I click the list that show the error , it cause that i can't get the value and pass it to another file what i need it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No errors anymore, you can look at this share [this online solution/editor](https://codesandbox.io/s/DJj6ogW5)  on code sandbox.

You need to change to the following + console.dir:

```
const VideoListItem = (props) => {
  console.dir(props);
  const imageUrl = video.snippet.thumbnails.default.url;
  return (
    <li onClick={props.onVideoSelect(props.video)} className="list-group-item">
      <div className="video-list media">
        <div className="media-left">
          <img className="media-object" src={imageUrl} />
        </div>
        <div className="media-body">
          <div className="media-heading">{video.snippet.title}</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </li>
  );
};
```

and change to:

```
class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    ......
    this.onVideoSelect.bind(this);
}
onVideoSelect(video){
   this.setState({selectedVideo:video});
  }
render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <SearchBar />
        <VideoDetail video={this.state.selectedVideo} />
        <VideoList
          onVideoSelect={ selectedVideo => onVideoSelect(selectedVideo) }
          videos={this.state.videos} />
      </div>
    );
  }
```

Here is the console.log/output and code image when i perform select video:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your help , i write your code step by step , i still get the error `Uncaught TypeError: onVideoSelect is not a function` , i think that i don't type it wrong probably.

Comment: @徐博俊 have a look at the code sandbox link i provided.

Comment: Thanks you very much , i fix the problem now . God bless you.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
  selectVideo = selectedVideo => this.setState({selectedVideo})

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <SearchBar />
        <VideoDetail video={this.state.selectedVideo} />
        <VideoList
          onVideoSelect={this.selectVideo}
          videos={this.state.videos} />
      </div>
    );
  }
```

It is important that you declare selectVideo on the same level as render inside class App

Comment: Thanks for your help , when i try the code , i get the error is `bundle.js:47 Uncaught Error: Cannot find module "./src/index.js"` it even let me compile it fail, i don't understand it.

Comment: Ahh sorry without const in front of selectVideo

Comment: Thanks again , i have tried it but without const , i will get the error `bundle.js:148 Uncaught ReferenceError: selectVideo is not defined`

Comment: ahh sorry again it should also be: {this.selectVideo}